# Kotlin Null pointer exception

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to display emails of users stored in firebase database.
I've this below code

```
    snapsListView = findViewById(R.id.snapsList)
    val adapter = emails?.let { ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, it) }
    snapsListView?.adapter = adapter

    auth.currentUser?.uid?.let { FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(it).child("snaps").addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener{
        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            emails?.add(snapshot.child("from").value as String)

            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            try {
                for(x in emails!!){
                    Log.i("Emails", x)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

Emails are present in the database and as per the hierrarchy also, users-> uid->snaps and snaps contains the email in "from"

Don't know what is causing this error, or how do i resolve this.

Always getting null pointer exception

Comment: The `emails` variable which you are iterating into is null.

Comment: yes i figured that out, it was initalized to null

Comment: what was happening when i tried to add the value in email

Comment: The `?.` is safe call operator, it says if the left side is not null then call `add()` and return whatever `add` will return otherwise do nothing and return null. (The return here is of line which you can store, it isn't returning from function :^))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `!!` operator you have *asserted* that `emails` is not `null`. However, Kotlin thrown runtime exception because `emails` is `null` actually. Consider replacing `!!` with safe-access:

```kotlin
emails?.let { for (x in it) Log.i("Emails", x) }
```